# Achieving seamless front/back camera switching with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm developing a photo app using AVFoundation and when I switch from front to rear camera (and vice-versa), I've noticed my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is briefly darkened immediately after the switch. It's not an enormous deal, but it does make the transition look very amateurish. Has anyone else experienced this/found a solution?